# How do I change the index of a TableItem?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Inside an SWT Table I have many TableItems.
I want to move one of them from index X to index Y.
Is there a way to do that?  How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct method to do this. But as a workaround, try the below method. I have used something similar once.

```
public void moveTableItem(Table table, int from, int to) {
    TableItem item2Move = table.getItem(from);
    TableItem newTableItem = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE, to);
    newTableItem.setText(item2Move.getText());
    // You may want to clone the entire item here; and not just the text.

    // Dispose off, the old item.
    item2Move.dispose();

}
```

Comment: I like the sound of that!  I'll try it out.  Thank you.